# Automatically restarting a child python process in kubernetes

Tags: python

I have a Python application which runs as the main process in a kubernetes pod, and this process kicks off some child processes to long poll a list of SQS queues (1 process per queue). Occasionally, one of the processes becomes a zombie and stops processing, and hangs up all other processes too, including the parent.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PROCESSES = []
    for queue, module in qfmapper.items():
        PROCESSES.append(Process(target=poll_for_messages, args=(queue,module)))

    for process in PROCESSES:
        process.start()

    for process in PROCESSES:
        process.join()
```

I've tried handling the `SIGCHLD` signal in the parent before it kicks off the children, but that doesn't seem to kill the parent if one of the children are killed. I know this leaves behind other child processes, but since kubernetes kills the pod if PID 1 dies, it shouldn't matter. This however doesn't seem to work, as the parent doesn't react to it. I'm assuming this is because process.join() blocks the parent.

So I've tried replacing individual `Process` calls with a `Pool`:

```
with contextlib.closing(mp.Pool(len(qfmapper))) as pool:
  for queue, module in qfmapper.items():
    pool.apply_async(poll_for_messages, args=(queue, module))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This again kicks off the polling processes as expected, but killing one doesn't seem to get replaced with the same call again. It spins up another worker to maintain the `Pool`, but it doesn't kick it off with the same arguments that the original `apply_async` call does.

I also tried using `map`, and that *does* restart the process if killed, but doesn't loop through all of the queues in my list; it just does the first one in the list multiple times. I've also tried `starmap`, and just used the for loop to build a list of iterables, but again that doesn't recover if one of the workers is killed.

So, ultimately, this comes back to the title of this question. How do you automatically restart a process that has died / been killed? I've searched high and low and I can't seem to find any answers for what seems to me like a "normal" thing to want to do. This is all running on Python 3.7.3, but I can upgrade to 3.8 if it has any features worth using to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why not make your life much easier and use threads?

Comment: It sounds like `map_async` is your answer and you're using it wrong.

Comment: Sorry @mikeLundquist, I meant to write that ```map``` starts again. I've tried using ```starmap``` with a list of iterables but it doesn't seem to recover like ```map``` does.
@coderanger My understanding is that threads will share the global interpreter lock, and thus things can get hung up while waiting for other threads?

Comment: Do you accept a good solution using external tool or are you looking for a pure python solution, exclusively?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but it would have to be something that will be able to run in a pod as well; whether that be sidecar or something else that calls the initial python process.

Comment: >but that doesn't seem to kill the parent if one of the children are killed   -- Am I right that you are OK with the parent process restart ?  In such a case isn't it easier to restart whole Pod (by means of healthprobes, etc)?   Alternatively it is possible to use python threads, so "main" thread is blocked until the "child" thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs. And after that to spawn child one more time?